# Выполняется ли PHP-скрипт при закрытии браузера?

Tags: php

Аяксом отправляется post-запрос php-скрипту. Скрипт выполняется в течение нескольких десятков секунд. Будет ли прервано выполнение скрипта при закрытии браузера?

Я понимаю, что php-скрипт выполняется на стороне сервера и по идее закрытие браузера не должно прекратить выполнение скрипта. Но хочу быть уверен на 100%.

Comment: да, если [постелить сломы](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ignore-user-abort.php) (на самом деле, в большинстве случаев даже без этого должно работать)

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что если скрипт ничего не возвращает и не выводит ничего на странице, а только пишет данные в базу, то использовать ignore_user_abort нет необходимости?

Comment: Да, но сама задумка скорее всего вредит архитектуре. Вещи с таким временем выполнения не должны делаться через веб-сервер, это занимает одного из воркеров и роняет общую устойчивость сервера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сторона сервера никак не зависит от браузера. Серверу вообще до фонаря чем вы запускали скрипт. Вы его запустили, он будет исполнен, если конечно другие факторы не помешают. Ответ: нет, не прекратится.